# Laravel blade - Creating an HTML id placeholder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In laravel blade, how do I create a placehold for an ID of a HTML element. This is what I already tried:

**app.blade.php**

`<div id="@yield('container-id', 'main-container')" class="panel panel-default">`

**show.blade.php**

```
@section('container-id')
    messages
@endsection
```

**resolves to:**

```
<div id="   messages
" class="panel panel-default">
```

**expected:**

`<div id="messages" class="panel panel-default">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is not a problem at all. But if you don't want to see that space and break, then do it in one line.

```
@section('container-id'){{"messages"}}@endsection
```

Comment: doing so results in:
`<div id="main-container" class="panel panel-default">` and adds `messages@endsection
   




 `to the first line of the body.

Comment: never would've thought of this. Thanks!